# Selecting Nested Elements using querySelector

Tags: javascript

I don't know if this is the right method but I'm trying to use querySelector to grab the second span that resides in the first hyperlink.

```
<ul className="h-topnav menu horizontal">
    <li>
        <Link to={"/"} ref="link" className="margin-top-10">
            <span className="underline-grey large underlined">
            <span className="font-black">H</span><span className="grey-dark">ome</span></span>
        </Link>
    </li>
    <li>
        <Link to={"/about"} ref="link" className="margin-top-10">
            <span className="underline-grey large underlined">
            <span className="font-black">A</span><span className="grey-dark">bout</span></span>
        </Link>
        </li>
    <li>
        <Link to={"/jobs"} ref="link" className="margin-top-10">
            <span className="underline-grey large underlined">
            <span className="font-black">J</span><span className="grey-dark">obs</span></span>
        </Link>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm able to get the  element via the 'h-topnav' class as a marker, but now I'm trying to dig deeper down from that point on:

```
theUL.querySelector('li[0] a span[1].textContent').to.equal("Home")
```

Comment: [`document.querySelector('ul li a span:nth-child(1)').textContent.trim()`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/h3vxjyv2/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
theUL.querySelector("li:nth-child(1) span").textContent.trim()
```

Note the call to `.trim()` to remove white space from result of call to `.textContent`

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var theUL = document.querySelector("ul");
  console.log(theUL.querySelector("li:nth-child(1) span").textContent.trim() === "Home");
}
```

```html
<ul className="h-topnav menu horizontal">
  <li>
    <Link to={ "/"} ref="link" className="margin-top-10">
    <span className="underline-grey large underlined">
            <span className="font-black">H</span><span className="grey-dark">ome</span></span>
    </Link>
  </li>
  <li>
    <Link to={ "/about"} ref="link" className="margin-top-10">
    <span className="underline-grey large underlined">
            <span className="font-black">A</span><span className="grey-dark">bout</span></span>
    </Link>
  </li>
  <li>
    <Link to={ "/jobs"} ref="link" className="margin-top-10">
    <span className="underline-grey large underlined">
            <span className="font-black">J</span><span className="grey-dark">obs</span></span>
    </Link>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you missed the a or can you skip the hyperlink if the spans are between the hyperlink tags? (<Link>spans are here</Link>

Comment: The `span` is a descendant of `li` element. Can you create a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net or plnkr http://plnkr.co to demonstrate `null` being returned?

Answer (score 0):

You're searching for the `:first-child` pseudo-selector:

```js
var text = theUL.querySelector('li:first-child > a > span').textContent
console.log(text)
```

```html
<ul class="h-topnav menu horizontal">
    <li>
        <a href="/" ref="link" class="margin-top-10">
            <span class="underline-grey large underlined">
            <span class="font-black">H</span><span class="grey-dark">ome</span></span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/about" ref="link" class="margin-top-10">
            <span class="underline-grey large underlined">
            <span class="font-black">A</span><span class="grey-dark">bout</span></span>
        </a>
        </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/jobs" ref="link" class="margin-top-10">
            <span class="underline-grey large underlined">
            <span class="font-black">J</span><span class="grey-dark">obs</span></span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

As an aside: I might also suggest styling your link text using the `:first-letter` CSS pseudo-selector, which would greatly simplify your markup.

```
.h-topnav span:first-letter {
    color: black;
}
.h-topnav span {
    color: gray;
}
```

```html
<a href="/" ref="link" class="margin-top-10">
    <span class="underline-grey large underlined">Home</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `first-child` of `li` and `nth-child(1)` of `span` as below.

```js
var theUL = document.getElementsByClassName('h-topnav')[0];
console.log(theUL.querySelector('li:first-child a span:nth-child(1)').textContent);
```

```html
<ul class="h-topnav menu horizontal">
    <li>
        <a to={"/"} ref="link" className="margin-top-10">
            <span className="underline-grey large underlined">
            <span className="font-black">H</span><span className="grey-dark">ome</span></span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a to={"/about"} ref="link" className="margin-top-10">
            <span className="underline-grey large underlined">
            <span className="font-black">A</span><span className="grey-dark">bout</span></span>
        </a>
        </li>
    <li>
        <a to={"/jobs"} ref="link" className="margin-top-10">
            <span className="underline-grey large underlined">
            <span className="font-black">J</span><span className="grey-dark">obs</span></span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the simplest solution that worked: li:nth-child(1) span:nth-child(1)

Comment: `li:nth-child(1) span:nth-child(1)` selector should return same result as `li:nth-child(1) span`